# The items on a google map can have text below the item image? (programatically)

Tags: google-maps

For example, if i have a lot of items on my mapview, each one representing GPS coordinates of friends, i want that below the image of the item to have writted the name of each friend

is this possible?

(programatically)

Comment: Some time ago I was working with markers clustering - many markers on the map, when zoom out, it merged that markers and wrote down on that marker a number of markers that it claim. So I think that it is possible to place a text below the marker too.

Comment: Have you considered the `infowindow`?

Comment: can you explain me a little more? i am programming on android

Comment: use fromLatLngToDivPixel  to get the offset of the div below the marker ,create your own div with that offset and append it to G_MAP_MAP_PANE

Comment: wow, i dont understand anything, code example will be perfect, can you do one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some neat code and ideas here on extending the Google Map Marker to include a label.. perhaps just your friends initials would fit nicely.. ?

http://www.googlemapsbook.com/2007/01/22/extending-gmarker/

Duncan.